# Hovering over parent element to display overlayed child element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image with a font awesome overlay of a plus. When I hover over the image (a tag) I want to display the plus, but I'm not sure if I have the correct css. The plus doesn't show when I hover over it!

Here is my code

```css
a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover > .addTeacher {
  display: normal;
}
```

```html
<a class="registerTeacherAsHost" data-event-id=@Model.SpaceEvent.YogaSpaceEventId>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/User_small_compressed_blue.png" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" alt="no teacher">
      <i style="display:none; z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 35%; right: 42%; color: grey;" class="addTeacher fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
    </div>

  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: should be `display:block` instead of `display: normal`

Comment: There is no property name `normal` for `display`, use `block` instead!

Comment: really!? It comes up in the intelllisense list

Comment: either way it's still not showing with block!

Comment: this works https://jsfiddle.net/zaescrsa/

Comment: A copy and paste solution is available for you in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS should look like this

```
a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
a.registerTeacherAsHost .addTeacher { display: none; }
a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover .addTeacher {
    display: block;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<a class="registerTeacherAsHost" data-event-id=@Model.SpaceEvent.YogaSpaceEventId>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/User_small_compressed_blue.png" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" alt="no teacher">
            <i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 35%; right: 42%; color: grey;" class="addTeacher fa fa-plus fa-2x">asd</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

There were three problems with your code,

- You were using the ">" selector which will only select the child element (.addTeacher) which is right after the parent element (.registerTeacherAsHost) which in you case doesn't work.
- Other than that, the problem was with HTML where you declared the CSS for `.addTeacher` in the style tag, browsers take the CSS in this tag into consideration over any other stylesheets. One thing that could've worked was adding an `!important` to `a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover .addTeacher { display: block !important; }`. But it's better to write styles in a stylesheet and avoid using the `!important` as much as possible.
- Next thing was, you were using `display: normal` which I've never heard of before and I think the browser hasn't too. `display: block` does the job.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ncprd90/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and it was one of the options that came up in the list as I started typing. Don't know anything other then that.. But thanks, this helps explain!!

Answer (score 1):

There's been plenty wrong with your **`CSS`** which has been discussed already. I am focusing on a quick solution which goes here. Some adjustments have been made in the `HTML` structure and you are advised to avoid inline **`CSS`**. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
a.registerTeacherAsHost{
display:inline-block;
}

a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover .thumbnail img {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

a.registerTeacherAsHost:hover i.addTeacher {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.thumbnail{
position:relative;
max-width:100%;
}

i.addTeacher{
display:none;
z-index: 200;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
right: 42%;
color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="registerTeacherAsHost" data-event-id=@Model.SpaceEvent.YogaSpaceEventId>
  <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/09/24/106425_man_512x512.png" alt="no teacher">   
      <i class="addTeacher fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
     </div>
</a>
```